# sed can't replace substring with special characters

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

[Mac/Terminal] I'm trying to replace words in a sentence with red-colored versions of  them. I'm trying to use sed, but it's not outputting the result in the format I'm expecting. i.e.

```
for w in ${sp}; do
    msg=`echo $msg | sed "s/$w/\\033[1;31m$w\\033[0m/g"`
done
```

results in:

```
033[1;31mstb033[0m 033[1;31mshu033[0m 033[1;31mkok033[0m
```

where $sp is a list of a subset of words contained in $msg

the desired output would look like:

```
\033[1;31mstb\033[0m \033[1;31mshu\033[0m \033[1;31mkok\033[0m
```

and then my hope would be that echo -e would interpret this correctly and show the red coloring instead. So far, however, I seem to not understand quite correctly how sed works in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems hugely inefficient. Why do you not simply replace all the words in one go and put in the actual escape codes immediately?

```
sp='one two three'
msg='one little mouse, two little mice, three little mice'
echo "$msg" | sed -E "s/${sp// /|}/^[[1;31m&^[[0m/g"
```

Output (where I use bold to mark up the red color<sup>1</sup>):

`one little mouse, two little mice, three little mice`

The `sed -E` option is just to allow us to use a simpler regex syntax (on Linux and some other platforms, try `sed -r` or simply translate the script to Perl).

You would type <kbd>ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> where you see `^[` in the command line above.

If you need the message in a variable for repeated use, look at `printf -v`

---

<sup>1</sup> Looks like [Stack Overflow doesn't support `<span style="color:red">`](/a/35485694/874188), unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an array, and [`printf` instead of `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/13377)?

```
$ sp="Now is the time..."
$ w=( $sp )
$ printf -v output '\e[1;31m%s\e[0m ' "${w[@]}"
$ echo "$output"
Now is the time...
```

The output is obviously red, which [doesn't come across here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-stack-overflow-question-editor), but:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$output"
$'\E[1;31mNow\E[0m \E[1;31mis\E[0m \E[1;31mthe\E[0m \E[1;31mtime...\E[0m '
```

And if you don't like the trailing space, you can trim it with `${output% }`.

Comment: That just colors all the words, I *think* the OP wants to replace the words in `$msg` which occur in `$sp` (which probably contains something like `"ERROR WARNING INFO DEBUG"`).